# Import errors after upgrading django

Tags: django, python-poetry

After updating Django to version 4.2, I'm having several import issues, for example: "ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext' from 'django.utils.translation'". All the errors point to the configuration of my virtual environment, which is build using Poetry.

I have already cleared the cache and deleted the local directory (Cache). Everything (Django, Python, etc.) is in new versions and are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It was [deprecated at Django 3.0 and has now been removed.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30165)

You may find the [django-upgrade](https://pypi.org/project/django-upgrade/) package useful for automatically replacing `ugettext` with `gettext` and much more generally for finding and removing deprecations. (I found it very useful for converting all my URLS to use `path`).